# GWT 2.5.0 mvn install error "Rebind result <class> must be a class"

Tags: gwt, maven, maven-war-plugin, gwt-maven-plugin

**Problem**: I run `mvn install` on my GWT 2.5.0 project that I built with the [gwt-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html) and get the error `Rebind result 'c3gw.fwk.gui.client.ClientFactory' must be a class`.

This is a snippet of my pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
         <goals>
             <goal>compile</goal>
             <goal>test</goal>
             <goal>i18n</goal>
             <goal>resources</goal>
             <goal>generateAsync</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
     </executions>
     <configuration>
       <runTarget>C3gwGui.html</runTarget>
       <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
       <i18nMessagesBundle>c3gw.fwk.gui.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <phase>compile</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>exploded</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

This is a snippet of my C3gwGui.gwt.xml:

```
<replace-with class="c3gw.fwk.gui.client.ClientFactoryImpl">
    <when-type-is class="c3gw.fwk.gui.client.ClientFactory" />
</replace-with>
```

This is a snippet of the line where the error is thrown:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    ClientFactory clientFactory = GWT.create(ClientFactory.class);

    ...
}
```

ClientFactory is an interface and ClientFactoryImpl implements the interface.

**What I've figured out so far**: The code works perfectly fine in Eclipse when I run debug, it just doesn't work when I do mvn install. I've run all the goals available for gwt-maven-plugin (clean, compile, sources, etc...) and they all work so the only conclusion I can have at this point is that something is happening during the maven-war-plugin phase or much later.

I also took the basics of this code from the following [google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces) and they use an interface so it should work, assuming that the example project also works that is.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `war:exploded`? It shouldn't be needed, AFAICT it was a hack for devmode that shouldn't be needed anymore (if it was at any time)

Comment: Does the `com.mycompany.gwt.Module` module have an `inherits` statement for the `...C3gwGui` module?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that worked. It builds now. I'll check if that has caused any other unwanted effects however. Colin, sorry about that I corrected my pom.xml in the post above. It was the wrong pom info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing war:exploded, as Thomas indicated, solved the issue.